# latest commit showing in editor disappears in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea

i just updated to version 2020.3 from 2020.2.

Before, in editor, i could see the latest commit for every line right to the code. It also includes commit time.

But now it just disappears, i can't find where to turn it on.

[current appearance][1]

Update: i roll back to 2020.2, works fine now.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ajjVS.png

Thank you!

Comment: Seems you used some plugin for this feature.

Comment: it seems that you had GitToolbox plugin enable in previous versions.